# How to find the oldest reference to a term on the Web?

Tags: google-search

Now that "Sort by date" was [retired in Google Search](https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/3578318?hl=en&msgid=3882251) (except for news), how can I find the oldest reference to a term on the Web?

I also tried DuckDuckGo, and couldn't find an option to search by date

Answer (score 1):

1. You can search by date range: Tools > Any Time > Custom Range...
2. Attempt to make a custom variation of Google that will do this: https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/about/
3. This site: https://www.oldestsearch.com/